# Chrome extension storage types

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to develop an extension with javascript. I want to store data and access this data from every site. How should I go about this?

I used local storage but it could not be reached from all sites.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)